# Unable to get Callback Function to return values to parent function

Tags: node.js, callback

I am new to nodejs and struggling with callbacks. I have a callback-block which is expecting a value from a child function, however, I am not able to understand as to why the value is not being returned to the parent block - user.getUser. Help would be much appreciated.

***child function***

```
getUser(userEmail) {
    logger.info('fetching details for user '+userEmail)
    dynamoModel.get(userEmail, function(err, userModel){
    if(err) logger.error(err);
    logger.info(userModel);
    return userModel;
});
}
```

***callback***

```
user.getUser(email, function(err, userModel){
        logger.info('parent block->'+userModel);
    });
```

***output***

```
info: fetching details for user dhdhd
info:  email=dhdhd, password=ttjtkt, lastLogin=1498963442595, loginVendor=local, createdAt=Sun Jul 02 2017 12:44:02 GMT+1000 (AEST), updatedAt=Sun Jul 02 2017 12:44:02 GMT+1000 (AEST)
info: fetching details for user dhdhd
```

Also, I don't know why a call to the getUser function is happening multiple occations - as is eveident from multiple logs entry of -

```
info: fetching details for user dhdhd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the callback to the getUser() function, so it will be called once the dynamoModel.get(...)  will finish.

You are passing callback in the caller but not using it in getUser(...).

Returning value in getUser is meaningless because this is asynchronous code, the result will be received by the callback which you are passing in.

```
getUser(userEmail, done) {
    logger.info('fetching details for user '+userEmail)
    dynamoModel.get(userEmail, done)
}

user.getUser(email, function(err, userModel){
    if(err) logger.error(err);
    logger.info(userModel);
   });
```